# How to remove from the Pandas series the characters contained in the list (or series)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good afternoon. Checking the text in the column, I came across characters that I didn't need:

```
"|,|.|
|2|5|0|1|6|ё|–|8|3|-|c|t|r|l|+|e|n|g|i|w|s|k|z|«|(|)|»|—|9|7|?|o|b|a|/|f|v|:|%|4|!|;|h|y|u|d|&|j|p|x|m|і|№|ұ|…|қ|$|_|[|]|“|”|ғ|||​|>|−|„|*|¬|ү|ң|@|©|―|q|→|’|∙|·| |ә| |ө|š|é|=|­|×|″|⇑|⇐|⇒|‑|′|\|<|#|'|˚| |ü|̇|̆|•|½|¾|ń|¤|һ|ý|{|}| |‘|ā|í|﻿|ī|‎|ќ|ђ|°|‚|ѓ|џ|ļ|▶|新|千|歳|空|港|全|日|機|が|曲|り|き|れ|ず|に|雪|突|っ|込|む|ニ|ュ|ー|ス|¼|ù|~|ə|ў|ҳ|ό||€||¸|⠀|ä|¯|ツ|ї|ş|è|`|́|ҹ|®|²|‪|ç| |☑|️|‼|ú|‒|||||ó|±|ñ|ł|ش|ا|ه|ن|م|›| |£||||º
```

Text encoding - UTF8.

How do I correctly remove all these characters from a specific column (series) of a Pandas data frame?

I try

```py
template = bad_symbols[0].str.cat(sep='|')

print(template)

template = re.compile(template, re.UNICODE)

test = label_data['text'].str.replace(template, '', regex=True)
```

And I get the following error:

```
"|,|.|
|2|5|0|1|6|ё|–|8|3|-|c|t|r|l|+|e|n|g|i|w|s|k|z|«|(|)|»|—|9|7|?|o|b|a|/|f|v|:|%|4|!|;|h|y|u|d|&|j|p|x|m|і|№|ұ|…|қ|$|_|[|]|“|”|ғ|||​|>|−|„|*|¬|ү|ң|@|©|―|q|→|’|∙|·| |ә| |ө|š|é|=|­|×|″|⇑|⇐|⇒|‑|′|\|<|#|'|˚| |ü|̇|̆|•|½|¾|ń|¤|һ|ý|{|}| |‘|ā|í|﻿|ī|‎|ќ|ђ|°|‚|ѓ|џ|ļ|▶|新|千|歳|空|港|全|日|機|が|曲|り|き|れ|ず|に|雪|突|っ|込|む|ニ|ュ|ー|ス|¼|ù|~|ə|ў|ҳ|ό||€||¸|⠀|ä|¯|ツ|ї|ş|è|`|́|ҹ|®|²|‪|ç| |☑|️|‼|ú|‒|||||ó|±|ñ|ł|ش|ا|ه|ن|م|›| |£||||º
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-36817f343a8a> in <module>
      5 print(template)
      6 
----> 7 template = re.compile(template, re.UNICODE)
      8 
      9 test = label_data['text'].str.replace(template, '', regex=True)

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/sre_parse.py in _parse(source, state, verbose, nested, first)
    643             if not item or item[0][0] is AT:
    644                 raise source.error("nothing to repeat",
--> 645                                    source.tell() - here + len(this))
    646             if item[0][0] in _REPEATCODES:
    647                 raise source.error("multiple repeat",

error: nothing to repeat at position 36 (line 2, column 30)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your characters, use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape):

```
import re

template = '|'.join(map(re.escape, bad_symbols[0]))
```

Then, not need to compile, `pandas` will handle it for you:

```
test = label_data['text'].str.replace(template, '', regex=True, flags=re.UNICODE)
```